# how to map two unrelated classes in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am facing a problem regarding mapping classes.
 I have two classes Song and User

```
public class Song implements Serializable {
private Album album;
private String title;
private int rating;
private String artist;
private String composer;
private Genre genre;
private int songId;
//getters and setters
} 

public class user{
 private String userName;
 private String password;
 private int user_id;

//getters and setters
}
```

I have to map each user with the songs in his account. To do this i have a table user_songs_mapping table which has song_id and user_id as the columns... I am not getting how to map this relationship i hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You should use a many-to-many setting, e.g. with annotations you'd d:

```
class Song {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable( name = "user_songs_mapping",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "songid" ), //assuming the id column in the song table is named songid
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = " user_id", referencedColumnName = "userid" ) ) //assuming the id column in the user table is named userid
  Set<Users> users;
}

class User {
  @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "users" )
  Set<Song> songs;
}
```

Note that one side defines the table and the other side just declares where to find the mapping. In my example `Song` would be the owning side, i.e. you'd need to update the users set in `Song` to get changes persisted. If you want `User` to be the owning side just switch annotations and join columns.

*Update:* Rereading your question I assume you want a unidirectional association user->songs. Thus only add the relation to `User`:

```
class User{
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable( name = "user_songs_mapping",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = " user_id", referencedColumnName = "userid" ),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "songid" ) )
  Set<Song> songs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml to map table to class so it will be like that:

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="User" table="user">      
   <!-- column attribute contains the name using in data base and name attribute contains the name using in calss -->
      <id name="id" type="int" column="user_id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <set name="songs" cascade="save-update" table="user_songs_mapping">
         <key column="user_id"/>
         <many-to-many column="song_id" class="Song"/>
      </set>
      <property name="userName" column="user_name" type="string"/>      
      <!-- other properties-->
   </class>

   <class name="Song" table="song"> 
      <id name="songId" type="int" column="song_id">   
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="title" column="title" type="string"/>
   <!-- other properties-->  
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: should i not specify anything related to user class in Song mapping?

Comment: If you wish getting users associated to a song you can indicate a set of users the same way as songs.

Answer (score 0):

Its a classic case of many to many relationship with a jointable.

both class declaration should have @manyToMany annotation on the collection having other class objects.
Make one class a joinowner by having the jointable annotation *"here User"* and put just mappedby attribute in other class *"here Song"*.
Example is as below.

```
public class User{

 @Id
 @Column(name="USER_ID") 
 private int user_id;

 @Column(name="USER_NAME")
 private String userName;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {Google this and use what you want as per your requarement})
 @JoinTable(name="USER_SONGS_MAPPING", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SONG_ID")})
  private Set<Song> songs= new HashSet<Song>();

//getters and setters
}

public class Song {

// Other fileds

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="songs")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

//getters and setters
}
```

For more info use hibernate docs
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html